# Directly open watsapp chat window without showing share on watsapp page in Ionic v3?

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, ionic3, whatsapp

I am using WhatsApp API to open WhatsApp App in Ionic V3. Earlier everything was working fine. Now when ever i click chat button it is showing additional page that says "Message +91 xxxxxxxxx on WhatsApp" with a green button "Message". Then i have to click this green button to open WhatsApp App. Is there any way to skip this.

This is the WhatsApp API which i am using :
`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91xxxxxxxxxx`

I also tried :
`https://wa.me/15551234567`

This is the additional page which i am getting : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1acmF1GZsJFyRjuE_oKc_a8-feSpC75ed/view?usp=sharing

Any help appreciate. Thanks in advance.